# Not able to register using class based view.?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want to work with company model where i am to register using subdomain and have to login using that same domain name.

I created a model using following fields :

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    sub_domain = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_limit = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRIES, blank=True, null=True)
```

And my registration form is like something below:

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['name', 'address',
                  'sub_domain', 'country']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs = {"class": "form-control"}
```

But when it comes to views i dont know how to handle class based views and as i am a newbie facing problem to save data in db.

views.py

```
class RegistrationView(CreateView):
    model = Company
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    template_name = "company_register.html"

    def is_valid(self, form):
        company = Company.objects.create_company(form.cleaned_data['name'],
                                                 form.cleaned_data['address'],
                                                 form.cleaned_data['sub_domain'],
                                                 form.cleaned_data['country'])
        company.save()
        return super(RegistrationView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RegistrationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Please someone help!!!

Comment: The method you want to override is `form_valid` not `is_valid` in your view

Comment: @IainShelvington Can you modify my view and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fully understand what's happening, we should also see that the method `create_company` is doing.

Other than that, CreateView uses the method `form_valid` and not `is_valid`. I valid is a method from the form, not the view. It would be something like this:

```py
class RegistrationView(CreateView):
    model = Company
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    template_name = "company_register.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        company = form.save()
        subdomain = form.cleaned_data['sub_domain']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(USE_subdomain_IN_YOUR_URL_HERE)
```

Instead of calling `super`, since the `form_valid` method already has access to the subdomain, call `HttpResponseRedirect` in order to redirect there.

What I didn't understand was the 'login' part as your Company model doesn't seem the be extending a User model.

Comment: I am getting 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_company'

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using that because you've defined that method. If you didn't, that's why the error occurs. 

I'll edit my answer with a different approach.